# Can you have iOS 2 different targets with the same product name in Xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I have a project with 2 targets for an iOS app: Pro and Lite:

They have the same product name.
They have different icons.
They have different bundle ids.

I used to just be able to switch the scheme on the top left in Xcode to run either the Pro or the Lite version, and they could coexist on one phone as two completely separate apps.

I just updated to Xcode 4.3.2 and now all kinds of stuff is going wrong. Sometimes I see 2 apps on the iPhone. Sometimes it overwrites the previously executed target with the new one. Sometimes it shows the wrong icon (Pro icon with Lite code).

I didn't change any code since I updated Xcode.

Did Xcode 4.3.2 break this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out you need to ensure your 2 targets have unique `bundle ids` as well as unique `product names`.

To get the apps to have the same name on the iPhone springboard, you can set the `bundle display name` to the same string.